# Null value returning from datagridview

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, datagridview

I have a table in data base,In which authors names are stored along with their Google citations. multiple authors are separated by comma. I split them and show them on data grid view using this code:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
{
   int GSCitations;
   {
        string paper = Convert.ToString(row[1]);
        Int32.TryParse(Convert.ToString(row[2]), out GSCitations);
        string str = Convert.ToString(row[0]);
        string[] result = str.Split(new Char[] { ',' });
        foreach (string author in result)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(id, author, paper, GSCitations);
            id++;
        }

   }
```

then i pick them from data grid view and tried to store them in data base using this code:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
 {
        try
         {
         mysqlStatement = "INSERT INTO test1(ID, Authors,Paper, GSCitations) VALUES('" + row.Cells[0].Value + "','" + row.Cells[1].Value + "','" + row.Cells[2].Value + "','" + row.Cells[3].Value +"');";
         mySqlCommand = new MySqlCommand(mysqlStatement, mySqlConnection);
         mySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();     
         }

        catch(Exception excep)
        {
         MessageBox.Show(excep.ToString()); 
        }
  }
```

But it throws exception, that id is null. as id is primary key it cant b null. in data grid                  view no id is null, but in storing it returns null id, right after one group of authors is splitted.I  mean if first paper is writen by  four authors. it returns null right after 4 rows and  then so on after every group. please help

Comment: Couple of things in your code *(but unrelated)* , first use [parameterized queries](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter) instead of concatenating queries. Second, how can you insert in the database with the same primary key again ? are you trying to update ?

Comment: What is value in ID? is it null? Is database table empty?

Comment: I truncate table every time i run the code , i am doing this just for checking purpose

Comment: yes table is empty. every time i insert

Comment: now i debug and check through break point that it goes to end of splitted group then null row is returned , then it starts from first row and goes upto 2nd group then from first to third then so on, why this?

Comment: null row? Means row==null is true after group ends or the value in row.Cells[0].Value is null?

Comment: Every value of cell in row is null after each group, moreover the row index of foreach loop become 0 when exception is raised so it start the loop from start. and throws exception on 2nd group and so on

Answer (score 1):

Need to properly debug the code and see the full code to give the exact reason of this behavior, but if you just want to make it work try this

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
 {
        if(row == null || row.Cells[0].Value == null)
           continue;

        try
         {
            mysqlStatement = "INSERT INTO test1(ID, Authors,Paper, GSCitations) VALUES('" + row.Cells[0].Value + "','" + row.Cells[1].Value + "','" + row.Cells[2].Value + "','" + row.Cells[3].Value +"');";
            mySqlCommand = new MySqlCommand(mysqlStatement, mySqlConnection);
            mySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();     
         }

        catch(Exception excep)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(excep.ToString()); 
        }
  }
```

Comment: No! i have tried this but it is not good way, I have 3 lac records mean the loop will return null value atleast 2 lac times, So it make a huge difference. I want to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Try to change ur cells[index] to cells[column name], i guess the index is the reason y your ID column return null

```
mysqlStatement = "INSERT INTO test1(ID, Authors,Paper, GSCitations) 
VALUES('" +row.Cells[YOUR COLUMN NAME].Value + "','" + 
row.Cells[YOUR COLUMN NAME].Value + "','" + 
row.Cells[YOUR COLUMN NAME].Value + "','" + 
row.Cells[YOUR COLUMN NAME].Value +"');";
```

Comment: because he is trying to insert something that not exist to database? so he got the null values?

Comment: can u try to check whether ur row.Cells[YOUR COLUMN NAME].Value contains any value?